# How to mock MongoClient in PHPUnit

Tags: php, mongodb, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm re-engineering an application, and I've chosen to use TDD to do it.  I'm new to TDD and have yet to fall in love with the process.  Currently, I've run into a problem that I'm not able to find any clear help on.  I might just be overthinking, but would certainly appreciate some help understanding what I'm running into.

The project I am working on persists to MongoDB.  I've been working with Mongo for a while now and like it a lot, but the PHP driver doesn't seem to fit into my limited understanding of how (and what) to test with a fake/mock.

Here is a sample class (I haven't checked to see if it will run):

```
class UserCollection {
    protected $_mongo_client; //connection to persistence layer (MongoDB or mock)

    public function __construct($mongo_client, $id = NULL) {
        $this->_mongo_client = $mongo_client;
    }

    public function getUserInfo($mid) {
        $collection = $this->_mongo_client->vertical->primaryMember;
        $user = $collection->findOne(array('memberId' => intval($mid)), array('memberId'=> true, 'name'=>true,'stats' => true));

        if($user['memberId']) {
            $return['status'] = "Success";
            $return['user'] = $user;
        } else {
            $return['status'] = "Failure";
            $return['message'] = "User not found";
        }

        return $return;
    }
}
```

As I understand it, if I am to create this writing the tests first, I need to create a fake for the DB - and I have been trying to come up with a mock to inject into the constructor.  How do I create a mock that handles lines like:

```
$collection = $this->_mongo_client->vertical->primaryMember;
```

I'm hoping that I am just overthinking the issue, and there is an easy or better way to do this.  At any rate I would appreciate any links, sage advice, or blunt corrections to my thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630595/test-mongodb-interactions-in-a-php-application-mocking) addresses this topic as well.

<strike>Phactory provides direct support for mocking MongoDB. [Here is a complete example](http://phactory.org/mongodb-guide/#phpunit-example) from the creators of Phactory in their [guide explaining how to mock MongoDB in PHP](http://phactory.org/mongodb-guide/).</strike>

**Edit**: The above links are now dead, and Phactory appears to be no-longer maintained. There's a new project called [`php-mongomock'](https://github.com/martin-helmich/php-mongomock) that aims to solve this problem:

```
use Helmich\MongoMock\MockCollection;

$collection = new MockCollection();
$collection->createIndex(['foo' => 1]);

$documentId = $collection->insertOne(['foo' => 'bar'])->insertedId();
$collection->updateOne(['_id' => $documentId], ['$set' => ['foo' => 'baz']]);
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who might stumble across this later, I found a couple of solutions.  In the case referenced above I realized that it is more appropriate to pass MongoCollection's in as dependancies, and those are very easy to mock.

However, as I am using Mockery for my mocking library, there are some options for handling "Demeter chains", like the one I asked specifically about:

```
$collection = $this->_mongo_client->vertical->primaryMember;
```

Here is a link to the docs:

http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html

It basically states that you can theoretically mock the chain like this:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('\MongoClient');
$mock->shouldReceive('vertical->primaryMember')->andReturn($mockMongoCollection);
```

You can return anything that you want, and seems like a pretty workable solution.